# Extract and copy rows and columns from a large text file

Tags: linux

In addition to my previous question - how canI extract values in the  Columns format from a large text file. Also If I want to extract out the value of the specific column. The text file looks like the attached image.

I want to extract out the RESOL and FSC values as Given in the text to plot it in Numbers or EXCEL.

To be more general - what should be done if I do want to extract the values to Part_FSC and CC later.

Thanks

Text File:

```
 Opening MRC/CCP4 file for WRITE...
 File      : map2.mrc
 NX, NY, NZ:    600   600   600
 MODE      : real


 SYMMETRY REDUNDANCY:    1


 Fraction_mask, Fraction_particle =    0.1193    0.0111

C                                                 sqrt       sqrt
C  NO.  RESOL  RING RAD   FSPR    FSC  Part_FSC  Part_SSNR   Rec_SSNR       CC  
C   2  952.50    0.0017   0.09  1.000     0.000   400.0145    479.40   0.1222   
C   3  476.25    0.0033   0.19  1.000     0.000   159.3959    159.98   0.1586   
C   4  317.50    0.0050   0.92  0.999     0.000    48.2248     43.27   0.0155   
C   5  238.12    0.0067   0.42  1.000     0.000    88.3074     76.69   0.2637   
C   6  190.50    0.0083   0.48  0.999     0.000    64.0162     56.25   0.4148   
C   7  158.75    0.0100   1.41  0.992     0.000    17.1695     15.64   0.1282   
C   8  136.07    0.0117   5.56  0.954     0.000     6.8244      6.47   0.0171   
C   9  119.06    0.0133   1.49  0.993     0.000    16.1918     16.42   0.2729   
C  10  105.83    0.0150   1.68  0.990     0.000    12.8313     13.83   0.3729   
C  11   95.25    0.0167   3.55  0.969     0.000     6.8012      7.95   0.2624   
C  12   86.59    0.0183  16.00  0.830     0.000     2.5273      3.13   0.0826
```

Comment: Maybe awk http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but should work

```
awk '$1 == "C"{printf "%s\t%s\n", $3,$6}' <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tink. It worked well! Any documentation will you recommend to understand the syntax and the regular expression. I am very new to this.

Comment: There's no regular expression in there. http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html is a good starting point.  Basically awk works line-oriented, and considers items separated by any number of whitespace as field separator.  $1 is the first field, $2 the second, and so forth.  What the awk command above does is check if the first field of any line equals "C"; if it doesn't the line is skipped, if it does the 3rd and 6th field get printed, separated by a TAB.  Feel free to upvote/accept the answer ;}